# ¿Cómo puedo borrar el .png que creo al añadir una persona

Tags: java, android

Cuando creo una persona en la `ListView` que relleno con los datos de una `Sqlite` tengo la opción de elegir una foto, cuando lo hago creo un *.png* en mi dispositivo. Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema viene que cuando elimino la persona de mi `ListView` el *.png* creado en mi dispositivo no se elimina. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al borrar la persona el *.png* asignado a esa persona se elimine del dispositivo?

`EditarPersona` : Aquí es donde añado, edito la Persona y creo los .png

```
public class EditarPersonaActivity extends Activity {

    private Button butonGuardar;
    private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
    private Bundle extras;
    private ImageView imagenPersona;
    private String ruta_imagen = "";
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "EditarPersonaActivity";
    private Persona persona;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editar_persona);

        butonGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonGuardar);
        imagenPersona = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);

        // imagen onclick para abrir la galería y donde se muestra la imagen seleccionada

        imagenPersona.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ventanaImagen();
            }
        });

        // Recupera en un Objeto Bundle si tiene valores que fueron pasados como
        // parametro de una actividad.
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

// comprueba los datos al editar la persona

        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            ruta_imagen = extras.getString("ruta_imagen");
            imagenPersona.setImageBitmap(crearThumb());
        }

        // Agrega nuevo registro de una persona.
        butonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /// comprueba el estado para editar la persona
                if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                    /// edita la persona
                    editarPersona();
                } else {
                    // añade la persona
                    insertarNuevoPersona();
                }
                // finaliza la actividad
                finish();
            }


        });
    }

    /// metodo para crear la persona
    private void insertarNuevoPersona() {
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);
        try {
            // Crear objeto Persona.
            persona = new Persona(ruta_imagen);
            // Se inserta una nueva persona.
            baseDatos.insertarPersona(persona);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Se cierra la base de datos.
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }

// metodo para editar la persona

    private void editarPersona() {
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);
        try {
            // Crear objeto persona.
            int id = extras.getInt("id");
            persona = new Persona(id, ruta_imagen);
            baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getRutaImagen());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }

    /// estado al editar la persona

    public boolean estadoEditarPersona() {
        // Si extras es diferente a null es porque tiene valores. En este caso
        // es porque se quiere editar una persona.
        if (extras != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    // Metodo que abre la galeria
    private void ventanaImagen() {
        try {
            final CharSequence[] items = { "Seleccionar de la galería" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Seleccionar una foto");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                //Define path donde sera guardada una nueva imagen con medidas 150x150px
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("data/Images");
                if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
                    String newFolder = "/data";
                    String newFolder1 = "/data/Images";
                    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);
                    File myNewFolder1 = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder1);
                    myNewFolder.mkdir(); //creo la carpeta
                    myNewFolder1.mkdir(); //creao la carpeta
                } else {
                }
                File file;
                if(ruta_imagen.isEmpty()) { //No contiene imagen
                    Log.e(TAG, "NO contiene imagen, crea imagen.");
                    file = new File(dir, "profile_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "Contiene imagen, path " + ruta_imagen);
                    file = new File(ruta_imagen);
                }
                if (!file.exists()) { //Si archivo no existe.
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile(); //Procede a crearlo.
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult() " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    //Redimensiona imagen.
                    Bitmap bitmapout = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);
                    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                    try {
                        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmapout.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                        fOut.flush();
                        fOut.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                    //Muestra imagen con nuevas medidas en ImageView.
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapout);
                    //Obtengo la ruta de la imagen creada en el dispositivo.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Ruta imagen en archivo : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    ruta_imagen = file.getAbsolutePath();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error obteniendo imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String ruta_imagen) {
        // Objetos.
        File imagenArchivo = new File(ruta_imagen);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (imagenArchivo.exists()) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagenArchivo.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap crearThumb(){
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(ruta_imagen);
        BitmapFactory.Options opciones = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen, opciones);
        int scaleW = opciones.outWidth / 854 + 1;
        int scaleH = opciones.outHeight / 480 + 1;
        int scale = Math.max(scaleW, scaleH);
        opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        opciones.inSampleSize = scale;
        opciones.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen, opciones);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`: Aquí desde un menú contextual en cada Item es donde elimino la persona

```
// menu contextual

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
                eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
        }
    }

// metodo que elimina la persona

    private void eliminarPersona(int id_persona){
        AlertDialog.Builder mensaje_dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final int v_id_persona = id_persona;
        mensaje_dialogo.setTitle("Importante");
        mensaje_dialogo.setMessage("¿Está seguro?");
        mensaje_dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        mensaje_dialogo.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                try{
                    baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);
                    recuperarTodasPersonas();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    baseDatos.cerrar();
                }
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.show();
    }
```

`DatabaseHandler`:

```
// metodo eliminaPersona

    public boolean eliminaPersona(long id){
        return this.getWritableDatabase().delete("Personas", "_id" + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor resalta la(s) línea(s) de código que elimina la imagen, solo distingo la línea de `eliminarPersona`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya guardas el path de la imagen en el objeto persona, puedes obtener el archivo al obtener el objeto persona mediante el id y eliminarlo mediante `file.delete()`, ejemplo:

```
 Persona persona = baseDatos.getPersona(v_id_persona);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Elimina persona e imagen con ruta: " +persona.getRutaImagen());
                    File file = new File(persona.getRutaImagen());
                    if(file.exists()) {//verifica existe archivo.
                        Log.i(TAG, file.delete()?"Archivo se elimino satisfactoriamente.":"hubo un error al eliminar el archivo."); //para eliminarlo!.
                    }
```

Este sería el método completo:

```
   private void eliminarPersona(int id_persona){
        AlertDialog.Builder mensaje_dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final int v_id_persona = id_persona;


        mensaje_dialogo.setTitle("Importante");
        mensaje_dialogo.setMessage("¿Está seguro?");
        mensaje_dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        mensaje_dialogo.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                try{

                    Persona persona = baseDatos.getPersona(v_id_persona);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Elimina persona e imagen con ruta: " +persona.getRutaImagen());
                    File file = new File(persona.getRutaImagen());
                    if(file.exists()) {//verifica existe archivo.
                        Log.i(TAG, file.delete()?"Archivo se elimino satisfactoriamente.":"hubo un error al eliminar el archivo."); //para eliminarlo!.
                    }

                    baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);
                    recuperarTodasPersonas();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    baseDatos.cerrar();
                }
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.show();
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias !

Comment: Que bien que funciono!, saludos. ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 0):

para ello debes haber guardar la "Ubicación del archivo .png" que se encuentra en tu dispositivo, puedes eliminarlo de la siguiente manera

```
File file = new File("Ubicación de archivo a eliminar"); 
file.delete();
if(file.exists()){
      file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
      if(file.exists()){
           getApplicationContext().deleteFile(file.getName());
      }
}
```